# Как передать параметры через консоль?

Tags: perl

Win Vista, 32bit, Strawberry PERL 5.12.0

Файл cnu.pl (3 строки):

```
use strict;
print @ARGV;
<>;
```

При вызове: "perl cnu.pl 1 2 3" выдаёт

> `Can't open 1: No such file or directory at cnu.pl line 3.`
> `Can't open 2: No such file or directory at cnu.pl line 3.`
> `Can't open 3: No such file or directory at cnu.pl line 3.`
> `123`

При вызове: "`cnu.pl 1 2 3`" запрашивает строку ввода и завершается, ничего не выводя на экран.

Т.е. видно, что при вызове через интерпретатор PERL рассматривает цифры и как файлы для чтения, и как параметры.

Можно ли как-то изменить его поведение, чтобы он не пытался открыть файлы с такими именами?
И главное: как организовать чтение параметров, если скрипт запущен вот так: "`cnu.pl 1 2 3`" (второй случай)?

Answer (score 1):

Уберите '<>';

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@ARGV);
```

Answer (score 0):

можно так:

```
use strict;
print while $_ = shift @ARGV;
<>;
```

Comment: А что должна делать строка `<>;`? Паузу?